# C# in linux environment

Tags: c#, linux, installation

I am currently working in C/C++ in a Unix environment and am new to Linux environments. I would like to learn about the Linux OS and learn C# as the next level of programming language for my career.

I decided to put Ubuntu Linux on my laptop. But I am not sure whether we can write, compile and run C# programs in Linux environments or not.

The only IDE I know for C# is MS Visual Studio. Is there are any possible way to work in C# in a Linux environment?

If I have no other option, I'll have both operating systems on my laptop - Vista to learn C# and Linux for the other OS.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Learn [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

> The Mono Project is an open
>   development initiative sponsored by
>   Novell to develop an open source, UNIX
>   version of the Microsoft .NET
>   development platform. Its objective is
>   to enable UNIX developers to build and
>   deploy cross-platform .NET
>   Applications. The project implements
>   various technologies developed by
>   Microsoft that have now been submitted
>   to the ECMA for standardization.

You can use the [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/Main_Page) IDE.

> MonoDevelop is a free GNOME IDE
>   primarily designed for C# and other
>   .NET languages.

Comment: Just be careful with what version you pick.
tried monodevelop last week on a mac and it crashed almost every 5 minutes when compiling a ASP.NET Application.

Comment: The default version that is downloaded on os x is 2.0 alpha. The stable version is 1.0. Also, you should know that the latest mono library doesn't support most of the asp.net 3.5 dlls. They basically support asp.net 2.0

Comment: I may add an answer later, but do note that as of 2015 Microsoft has released .NET Core, which will likely replace Mono in the near future.

Answer (score 6):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) is an open source .NET compiler, runtime and library.
[Monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) is an open source C# IDE, primarily intended for linux development. It includes a GUI designer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [wine](http://www.winehq.org/), which is a free implementation of Windows' API.
For this :
 sudo apt-get install wine
then you'll be able to run Microsoft applications and do [almost] everything you like.

EDIT : My mistake, [Visual Studio](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=11022) is not functional :-(

Answer (score 0):

A Vista virtual machine in seamless mode running Visual Studio?  Then it will appear to integrate into your desktop like any other app, but you'll have the benefit of running the real MS stuff (with C#, having real MS is still a benefit rather than a liability).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I see no one has mentioned Microsoft Visual Studio Code IDE.  This could be what you are looking for if you want to do C# in Linux.  As a relative NOOB I can say it brings Visual Studio to Linux.  If you need a GUI IDE in Linux, this was it for me.  see [instructions to install it here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux)